# Dynamic function call in Racket class combined with apply

Tags: scheme, racket

### TL;DR

What I'm looking for is a combination of the functions [`send/apply`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/ivaraccess.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fclass-internal..rkt%29._send%2Fapply%29%29) and [`dynamic-send`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/ivaraccess.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fclass-internal..rkt%29._dynamic-send%29%29). So that it finds a method of an object based on a symbol **and** unpacks a list of arguments.

### Background and more info

For a project I am sending some "commands" trough the network with Racket's `tcp-connect`. At the receivers end this command should execute a method from a class and pass along its parameters.

Consider the following received 'message':

```
(define message (list 'set-switch! '3 'on))
(define method-name (car msg))  ;'set-switch!
(define parameters (cdr msg))   ;(list '3 'on)
```

And the following class:

```
(define light%
  (class object%
    (super-new)

    ...

    (define/public (set-switch! id mode)
      (vector-set! switches id mode))))
```

The problem now is that when executing this statement

```
(dynamic-send light-class method-name parameters)
```

it perfectly finds the method `set-switch!` but it calls it with only one parameter `(list '3 'on)`.

The Racket [docs](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/ivaraccess.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fclass-internal..rkt%29._send%29%29) mention those three functions for classes:

- `(send obj-expr method-id arg)` which just executes a method of an object
- `(send/apply obj-expr method-id arg-list-expr)` which executes a method AND unpacks the argument list
- `(dynamic-send obj method-name v)` which finds a method-name based on a symbol

What I think I need is something like `(dynamic-send/apply obj method-name arg-list-expr)` which combines the last two mentioned.

*Note: I know that I could just simply accept lists as parameters and use `car` and `cdr` in the functions itself to get the right values. But that's not what I want.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dynamic-send` is a function (also known as procedure; e.g., `car`, `vector-set!`, `+`), so you can use [`apply`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._apply%29%29):

```
(apply dynamic-send light-class method-name parameters)
```

Or even simply:

```
(apply dynamic-send light-class message)
```

The reason why `send` has the `send/apply` variant is that `send` is a form (also known as syntax; e.g., `let`, `define`, `if`), so `apply` doesn't work and hence `send/apply` is separately provided.

Comment: Very simple indeed! Exactly what I needed. I guess I was thinking way to far about this. Thank you!